# CSS Animation isn't working

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I made 2 animation, the first one is working properly while the second isn't. Although both are almost identical, it just won't work. I would appreciate any help!

```css
#menuAnim1 {
  height: 8px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  animation: widthStretch 4s ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#menuAnim2 {
  width: 8px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  animation: heightStretch 4s ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes widthStretch {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes heightStretch {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='menuAnim1'></div>
<div id='menuAnim2'></div>
```

You could see what I mean now. The second one should be increasing in it's height, then cross the first one, but it's not.

Comment: i advice to take a look to my answer if you want to understand your issue as i don't agree at all with the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both your elements are using percentage values for the height/width in their animation and these values will be calculated relatively to their container (containing block) which is the body.

By default, the body is a block level element and its width will not depend on its content so percentage width on the animated divs will work fine BUT since the height of the body depend on its content (which is the case of all the elements) percentage height on the animated div won't work and fail to `auto`.

<sup>more details here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html</sup>

---

You have **to explicitely specify a height** for the body to make the animation working. You can try a fixed height and your element will grow from 0 to this height.

```css
body {
  height:100px;
}
#menuAnim1 {
  height: 8px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  animation: widthStretch 4s ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#menuAnim2 {
  width: 8px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  animation: heightStretch 4s ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes widthStretch {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes heightStretch {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='menuAnim1'></div>
<div id='menuAnim2'></div>
```

You can also specify `height:100%` on the body BUT this will also not work because the same logic will apply to body and its containing block (`html`) that has no height specified, so you have also to add `height:100%` to `html`. The last one will work because the containing block of `html` is the viewport where the dimension (height/width) are known and doesn't depend on the content.

```css
body,html {
  height:100%;
}
#menuAnim1 {
  height: 8px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  animation: widthStretch 4s ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#menuAnim2 {
  width: 8px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  animation: heightStretch 4s ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes widthStretch {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes heightStretch {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='menuAnim1'></div>
<div id='menuAnim2'></div>
```

---

**Why using position:absolute works ?**

Because adding `position:absolute` will make the element positioned relatively to the first non-static parent element and since there is no posisitioned parent element it will be **positioned relatively to the viewport** and percetange height behave differently with `positon:absolute`

> Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), **and this element is not absolutely positioned**, the value computes to 'auto'

This is logical since a `position:absolute` element will not contribute on the height of its containing block since it's removed from the flow.

Now the viewport has a height and width that are simply the height/width of your browser so `height:100%` will be all the screen height.

```css
#menuAnim1 {
  height: 8px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  animation: widthStretch 4s ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#menuAnim2 {
  width: 8px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  animation: heightStretch 4s ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes widthStretch {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes heightStretch {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='menuAnim1'></div>
<div id='menuAnim2'></div>
```

Try to make your body `position:relative`. Your element will now be positionned relatively to the body and you will see that the animation will also work but with a *strange* reuslt.

Like I said before `height:100%` will refer to the containing block and in this case its the `body` and the height of the `body` is filled with the other element and it's exactly 8px.

```css
body {
  position:relative;
}

#menuAnim1 {
  height: 8px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  animation: widthStretch 4s ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#menuAnim2 {
  width: 8px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  animation: heightStretch 4s ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes widthStretch {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes heightStretch {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='menuAnim1'></div>
<div id='menuAnim2'></div>
```

Comment: A very detailed answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## menuAnim2 css postion needs to change from relative to absolute, Now its working...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#menuAnim1 {
 height: 8px;
 background: black;
 position: relative;
 top: 50px;
 animation: widthStretch 4s ease-out;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#menuAnim2 {
 width: 8px;
 background: black;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50px;
 animation: heightStretch 4s ease-out;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes widthStretch {
 from {width:0;}
 to {width:100%;}
}
@keyframes heightStretch {
 from {height:0;}
 to {height:100%;}
}
</style>
<script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='menuAnim1'></div>
<div id='menuAnim2'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! But I don't get why you need to change the second one to `position: absolute` while the first one remains `relative`?

Comment: @AzDeveloper please refer this link then you will understand about absolute & relative position https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_absolute

Comment: And if this is the solution of your question then please accept is as solution, Thanks

Comment: Tried to accept it when you first post, says 9 minutes later. The solution is working but I'm still kinda confuse about the `absolute` one. I get how `absolute` is relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (in this case, `<body`) but `#menuAnim1` still work fine.

Comment: Have you referred the link which I send you above.? This is the basic example of absolute & relative postion

Comment: I did, actually way before I ask this question. If you don't want to explain, I could figure it our myself. Thanks for your help!  
**EDIT:** I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because, in `#menuAnim2` **the browser didn't have any info about 100% height** 
(Maybe 100vh or 100px or 0px).

So, another solution is add **the parent container** with a width and height.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#container {
   width: 50vw;
   height: 50vh;
}
#menuAnim1 {
 height: 8px;
 background: black;
 position: relative;
 top: 50px;
 animation: widthStretch 4s ease-out;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#menuAnim2 {
 width: 8px;
 background: black;
 position: relative;
 left: 50px;
 animation: heightStretch 4s ease-out;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes widthStretch {
 from {width:0;}
 to {width:100%;}
}
@keyframes heightStretch {
 from {height:0;}
 to {height:100%;}
}
</style>
<script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
  <div id='menuAnim1'></div>
  <div id='menuAnim2'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I checked, apparently adding `position: absolute` will get `height: 100%` to work.

Comment: @AzDeveloper this the solution that need to be accepted, it has nothing to do with positining but with how  height works